# NetLogo GIS extension: Unsupported file type 21 error

Tags: gis, netlogo

I have been trying a add a .shp file (point) in NetLogo, but it showing this error:

Extension exception: unsupported shape type 21
error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET
called by procedure SETUP
called by Button 'Go'

Answer (score 1):

Type 21 is PointM - a point with measure (as part of geometry field, rather than as a separate field). Apparently NetLogo does not support this.

You can typically just remove M value from this file and convert geometry to regular Point, using GDAL ogr2ogr tool or many GIS systems, then try to load converted file to NetLogo.